# How to activate the favorites icon on the taskbar?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, gnome, gnome-3

My application is in the selected taskbar(GNOME, dash-to-panel). When a window opens, a new icon appears in the taskbar. How to make so that the favorites icon is activated and a new one does not appear (as in other applications: Gedit, Nautilus)

Answer: Need a correct StartupWMClass entry. Find entry: in a terminal xprop WM_CLASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have a launcher, in GNOME environments usually a .desktop file. This file tells the desktop which kind of application your app is, allows you to create right-click actions (such as New Window, New Private Window, etc.). Here is an example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=<Name of Your App>
Exec=<command to execute>
Terminal=<true/false depending on whether you run it on a terminal>
Icon=<name of the icon for your app (icon has to be installed on the system)>
Type=Application
Categories=<Office;Game;etc; (semi-colon separated)>
Keywords=Something;Other Thing;
```

There is a good guide by GNOME [here](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en).

Comment: No, all files exist. The program is packaged without errors and installed from the repository on github

Comment: To add to the answer above, try with Gtk.Application. links: https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GtkApplication, https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/application.html

Comment: Thanks, I decided. Need a correct StartupWMClass entry.  Find endtry: in a terminal xprop WM_CLASS